Why my component rerendes when I toogle the sidebar?
When I toggle the left sidebar, the ActionsList component rerenders, causing it to lose the loaded actions state. How can I prevent this from happening?
Please click here to checkout loom of the issue.
Current setup:
const ApiExplorer = ({ openapi, globalUrl }) => {
  const [actions, setActions] = useState([]);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const [serverurl, setServerUrl] = useState("");
  const [ExampleBody, setExampleBody] = useState(actions[0]?.body);
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState({});
  const [filteredActions, setFilteredActions] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const loadAction = 2;
  const loadedAction = useRef(null);

  const Action = React.memo(()=>{

   //action code
})

const ActionsList = memo(() => {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
    const [actionsList, setActionsList] = useState([]);
    const [selectedActionIndex, setSelectedActionIndex] = useState(0);
    const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true); // New state to track if there's more to load
    const itemPerLoad = 10; // Number of items to load per scroll
    const containerRef = useRef(null);
  
    // Initial loading and search filtering
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      if (searchQuery === "") {
        setActionsList(actions.slice(0, itemPerLoad));
      } else {
        const filtered = actions.filter(action =>
          action.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
        );
        setActionsList(filtered.slice(0, itemPerLoad));
      }
    }, [searchQuery]);
  
    // Load more items when scrolling down
    const loadMoreActions = () => {
      setActionsList((prevActions) => {
        const nextActions = actions.slice(prevActions.length, prevActions.length + itemPerLoad);
        if (nextActions.length < itemPerLoad) {
          setHasMore(false); // Stop loading if there are no more items
        }
        return [...prevActions, ...nextActions];
      });
    };
  
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const container = containerRef.current;
  
      if (container) {
        const scrollThreshold = 10;
        const isAtBottom =
          container.scrollTop + container.clientHeight >= container.scrollHeight - scrollThreshold;
  
        if (isAtBottom && hasMore) {
          loadMoreActions();
        }
      }
    };
  
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      const container = containerRef.current;
      if (container) {
        container.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }
      return () => {
        if (container) {
          container.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        }
      };
    }, [hasMore]);
  
    const handleActionClick = (index, action) => {
      setSelectedActionIndex(index);
      setExampleBody(action.example_response);
    };
  
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 350, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <TextField
          value={searchQuery}
          placeholder="Search here"
          onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            style: { height: 51 },
          }}
          sx={{
            marginLeft: 2,
            "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root fieldset": {
              border: "1px solid rgba(73, 73, 73, 1)",
            },
          }}
        />
        <div
          ref={containerRef}
          style={{
            marginLeft: 20,
            marginTop: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#1a1a1a',
            overflowY: 'auto',
            height: 'calc(100vh - 150px)',
          }}
        >
          {actionsList.length > 0 ? (
            actionsList.map((action, actionIndex) => (
              <Button
                key={action.name}
                sx={{
                  padding: "15px 5px",
                  textTransform: "none",
                  backgroundColor:
                    selectedActionIndex === actionIndex ? "#3f3f3f" : "transparent",
                  justifyContent: "flex-start",
                  marginBottom: "5px",
                  width: "100%",
                  display: "flex",
                  "&:hover": {
                    backgroundColor: "#2f2f2f",
                  },
                }}
                onClick={() => handleActionClick(actionIndex, action)}
              >
                <span
                  style={{
                    color: RequestMethods.find((method) => method.value === action.method)?.color,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    minWidth: 70,
                    textAlign: "start",
                  }}
                >
                  {action.method}
                </span>
                <span
                  style={{
                    color: "white",
                    textOverflow: "ellipsis",
                    overflow: "hidden",
                  }}
                >
                  {action.name.replaceAll("_", " ")}
                </span>
              </Button>
            ))
          ) : (
            <div style={{ padding: "15px", color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>
              No actions found
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },[]);

return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: "calc(100vh - 70px)",
      }}
    >
      <ActionsList />
      <div ref={loadedAction} style={{ width: "100%", height: '80vh', overflowY:'auto', marginLeft: 10, alignItems: "center" }}>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 1920, margin: 0, padding: 0}}>
          {/* <div
            style={{
              position: "fixed",
              top: 0,
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#1a1a1a",
              zIndex: 1000,
              padding: "10px 0 10px 10px",
            }}
          > */}
            <h1>
              {info?.title ? (
                <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <img
                    src={openapi?.info["x-logo"]}
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    alt="app logo"
                    style={{ marginLeft: 20, borderRadius: 8 }}
                  />
                  <Typography style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: 700, marginLeft: 20 }}>
                    {info.title}
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              ) : (
                "API Explorer"
              )}
            </h1>
          {/* </div> */}
      
          <div style={{ paddingTop: 20,}}> 
          {filteredActions.map((action, index) => (
            <Action
              key={index}
              action={action}
              index={index}
              serverurl={serverurl}
              setApiResponse={setApiResponse}
              setExampleBody={setExampleBody}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        </div>
        <ActionResponse apiResponse={apiResponse} ExampleBody={ExampleBody} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

Questions:

How can I stop ActionsList from resetting when toggling the sidebar?

Attempts:

I tried using useMemo and useCallback to prevent rerendering in the ActionsList component, but this didn't work.

I split the search bar and actions list into separate components, each with its own state, but the issue persisted.

I also tried moving the ActionsList logic to a higher-level component and transferring all relevant states and functions to the top, but with no success.


When logging inside ActionsList, I see duplicate logs each time I toggle the sidebar, confirming that it rerenders twice

ActionsList component does not rerenders, it unmounts and mounts on each render. Don't create component inside another component. You are recreating them on each render and the diffing algorithm can't compare that. Move Action and ActionsList outside of ApiExplorer. If you need something from the parent, pass them as props

Hey, really thank you for your suggestiong and it works really well.

@Oki Hey when I toogle sidebar with two actions in middle section than it took around 120ms to shift content but when there is more and more actions it took around 400ms how i can reduce this?

The first thing you have to do is to find the source of the issue. Debug. Delete things to see if they are the problem. Find exactly what causes the issue. What I see is that you have so many states, this might lead to performance issues. The fix comes after the problem, first find the problem
